# Windows 10 : Automatically open program on top of Login Screen at Startup

Tags: windows, windows-10

On a Windows 10 Pro, I would like a program to be launched at Startup before any user logs in (PC still locked).
The program is a full screen GUI application.

I found out how I could launch GUI apps on top of lock screen using the easy access button. What I would like is the program to be **automatically** launched **at startup** on top of the log in screen before anyone logs in.

I tried a scheduled task but the GUI did not show up on top of the log in screen like it does with the easy access button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not support what you want to achieve because it is a huge security risk.

You are not supposed to be able to start a program on the sign on screen either, but yes, there is a way to get around that.

Here's why...

When you start a program, it has to start in a user's environment in order to get certain accessrights, etc. Given that we are still at the sign-on screen, no user is logged in, so no user permissions can be retrieved. As a result any program that runs here, runs as NT\SYSTEM, a user that has every right on the system imaginable.

The sign-on area is its own desktop which is why you cannot normally run a program there. When you create a scheduled task or use computer startup script( not to be confused with logon script), the program starts, but you can't see the GUI still. Microsoft does not want to give you the ability to run a program with all rights that can allow anyone with basic computer skills to easily hack into the system, which is basically what this will allow you to do.

So that said, I would turn things around. Instead of trying to run a program on the sign-in desktop, create a user with limited privileges and use automatic logon to login with that user at startup, and auto start your program there, optionally creating an unlock screen to gain access to the system.

That said, it might also help to tell us what you want to accomplish. It may be that you are trying to solve a problem with the wrong solution and there's a much better solution for that. In that case, please create a new question and ask the original problem there instead of using this one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I want to install is a mini W10 computer running a full screen live demonstration program that I wrote at some clients places. I won't be in front of the computers all the time, and I want the client to be able to start the demo just by turning the computer ON. In addition I don't want anyone to be able to copy my program (hence the locked computer). As I own the computer and wrote the program, I see no security leak with the program running while the PC is locked, but don't know how to achieve this. ;-)

Comment: I managed to run the program while being locked using the "easy access" button hack, but the GUI disappears after a short time with the screen where you can enter your password or click on the "Ease of access" button

Comment: Look into kiosk mode with auto-login. Much easier approach. If the computer has only one account, set the password to nothing, and it will already autologin without the need to use a special registry hack to set autologin up with password.

Comment: Kiosk mode only allows for Windows Store App :/ I don't understand why TF if that... ^^ I managed to have my app running at startup but the taskbar is showing up on top of it, I don't know why...

Comment: There are other ways to get a kiosk mode. If you set any app as shell, it replaces the taskbar and desktop completely. Its the only thing that starts when you login.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: I googled for `alter windows shell` and the first result is https://realtimeissues.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/how-to-change-default-shell-of-windows-or-how-to-set-one-program-as-windows-shell-program/. Keep in mind that altering the shell can cause you to loose access, to do anything but run your program. So test in a test environment first in case you need to reinstall windows, such as a VM.